# Can someone explain . and -> in objective c?

Tags: objective-c

Help me :( i dont know why?

```
    @interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {
        BOOL isSearchOn; 
    }

    self->isSearchOn = NO; ( no error)
    self.isSearchOn = NO; ( error)
```

Answer (score 2):

Dot operator `.` is used to access `property`.

Arrow operator `->` is used to acces instance variable.

So you use

```
    self->isSearchOn = NO; // which is an instance not  a property
```

You can also use this way by skipping `self->`

```
    isSearchOn = NO;
```

Answer (score 2):

-> is the traditional C operator to access a member of a structure referenced by a pointer. Since Objective-C objects are (usually) used as pointers and an Objective-C class is a structure, you can use -> to access its members, which (usually) correspond to instance variables.

or

When applied to pointer arrow operator is equivalent to applying dot operator to pointee (ptr->field is equivalent to (*ptr).field)

or

pSomething->someMember

is equivalent to

(*pSomething).someMember

Answer (score 0):

. is used when you have a object and want to reference a attribute or a method, while you must use -> when holding the pointer only. instead of using -> you could aswell go for *. but I guess that you should in any case read about pointers in C.

Answer (score 0):

There are essentially three operators here, two of which are inherited from C and the third which is from Objective-C.

In C, `.` and `->` do the same thing—they retrieve a value from a struct—but `-` automatically dereferences a pointer to a struct, so the following two expressions are equivalent:

```
(*a).b
a->b
```

The second operator is simply syntactic sugar. Importantly, however, `.` doesn't make any sense when applied to a pointer—you have to use `->`.

Objective-C allows the use of `.` with an object pointer (and *only* with a pointer, since all Objective-C objects are pointers) to reference a *property* value, a much higher level construct than the C operators provide.

Therefore, you may use `.` on objects to retrieve properties defined in the interface with `@property`, but you will need to use `->` to retrieve ivars (instance variables) directly, which `isSearchOn` is in your example. However, it is usually better practice to expose variables using properties in Objective-C rather than refer to them directly using C's `->` operator.